# csv file gives strings when writing in floats

Tags: python, csv, casting

My `csv` file looks like:

```
"(-0.16192019, -0.007456851, 0.08841695)","(-0.10439591, 0.024501082, 0.12783173)","(-0.05965481, 0.049002163, 0.12144014)",...
```

but I don't want the quotes.

I wrote the function as:

```
for j in range(len(sensor_data)):
    with open(names[j] + "P" + str(i) + ".csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(sensor_data[j])
```

My `sensor_data[j]` is like this:

```
gyro.append((float(merge.iloc[j, 2]), float(merge.iloc[j, 3]), float(merge.iloc[j, 4]))) if merge.iloc[j, 0] == 'Gyroscope' \
             else acc.append((float(merge.iloc[j, 2]), float(merge.iloc[j, 3]), float(merge.iloc[j, 4])))
```

Why is it not printing out tuples of floats instead of tuples of strings?

```
merge = pd.read_csv(final_user_study_path + "/P" + str(i) + "/DataCollection/data/merge.csv")
```

Merge looks like:

```
Gyroscope,50958,-0.3387541,0.014913702,0.05965481
Gyroscope,50978,-0.23009712,0.03621899,0.044741105
LinearAcceleration,50979,-0.09891046,0.119261175,-0.108936176
Gyroscope,50998,-0.1768339,0.066046394,0.040480047
LinearAcceleration,50999,-0.0863409,0.18240824,-0.07152677
```

The types of all these values are strings.

I want:

```
(-0.16192019, -0.007456851, 0.08841695),(-0.10439591, 0.024501082, 0.12783173),(-0.05965481, 0.049002163, 0.12144014),...
```

Comment: where is `merge` defined?

Comment: Edited problem statement

Comment: Edit problem statement

Comment: Your required output format is not CSV format. If you opened that in Excel you would see cells containing the brackets e.g. `(-0.10439591`. Tuples are not CSV format.

Comment: I want each value in the CSV to be a tuple.

Comment: Try the following: `writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`

Comment: But if tuples are not csv format, is it in my best interest, to unpack the tuples?

Comment: Yes, it would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the `csv.writer()` from adding quotes when needed (because it spotted a delimiter in a cell), add the `quoting` parameter as follows:

```
writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

See the CSV docs: [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE)

It would though be preferable to unpack the tuples so they each correctly get their own cell without any extra parentheses. This could possibly be done using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), to collapse all the tuples into a single list. for example:

```
from itertools import chain

row = [(-0.16192019, -0.007456851, 0.08841695), (-0.10439591, 0.024501082, 0.12783173), (-0.05965481, 0.049002163, 0.12144014)]

print row
print list(chain.from_iterable(row))
```

This would display:

```
[(-0.16192019, -0.007456851, 0.08841695), (-0.10439591, 0.024501082, 0.12783173), (-0.05965481, 0.049002163, 0.12144014)]
[-0.16192019, -0.007456851, 0.08841695, -0.10439591, 0.024501082, 0.12783173, -0.05965481, 0.049002163, 0.12144014]
```

As you can see, the second line shows that all of the tuples have been flattened into a single list.

Comment: What if I wanted the tuples to have certain labels. For example (0, 1, 2) when unpacked becomes [0, 1, 2]. I want each of those in a separate column in the csv.

Comment: You would need to write the rows one at a time using `.writerow()`. For each row use `chain.from_iterable()` to flatten the tuples into a single list.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realized your solution gave me exactly what I needed.